# DocuSign: multiple recipients, one signature

Tags: php, docusignapi

Using the API to send out documents from a small finance company. In paper-space, a contract might be signed by "a company representative", i.e. the employee of record, or the employee's boss, or the team manager, whoever happens to be free at the time. Is it possible to have more than one recipient for a signature tab where one of them needs to sign? Y'know, whoever gets to it first?

I could also handle this with a common email address, but the less I have to ask them to do the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called a signing group and you can do that from the API.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-create-a-signing-group

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-requesting-signature-signing-group

PHP code:

```
# $signing_group_id should hold the string with the Signing Group ID   
$signer1 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
    'name' => 'test1', # Signing group name
    'signing_group_id' => $signing_group_id,
    'recipient_id' => '1']);
```